# Identity 2.0 / Owin / ApplicationUser from azure Webjob

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, owin, azure-webjobs

I am trying to run cleanup jobs from my azure Webjob for my mvc application. I can do standard database updates no problem but am unable to cleanup the aspnetuser accounts as I cannot get an ApplicationUser context as no startup class for Owin.

Anyone got any ideas on how this can be done or some dummy code?  My google searches have come up blank thus far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am running ASP.net MVC 5 with VS 2015

Actually even if the `ApplicationUserManager` requires an `OwinContext`, you can get rid of the `OwinContext`.
The `OwinContext` is only useful for accessing the `ApplicationDbConbtext` that is bound to the `OWinContext`.

So I refactored the `Create` factory methods of `ApplicationUserManager` in order to be able to manage the users, at startup (or in a WebJob), without any `OwinContext` :

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(
                  IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
                  IOwinContext context)
{
    ApplicationDbContext dbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
    return Create(options, dbContext);
}

internal static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, Applicatio
{
    // Create ApplicationUserManager myself instead of finding it on OwinContext
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

    // old code already generated by VS wizard
}
```

Then I use the `ApplicationUserManager` :

```
using (ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())  
{
    var options = new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>
    {
        //DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider(),
    };
    ApplicationUserManager userManager = ApplicationUserManager.Create(options, applicationDbContext);
    // ApplicationRoleManager has been changed the same way to be usable without OwinContext
    ApplicationRoleManager appRoleManager = ApplicationRoleManager.Create(applicationDbContext);

    //  ... Code using ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationRoleManager
    ApplicationUser appUser = userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email).Result;
    // ...
    IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, password).Result;

    }
}
```

Hope it helps